# How to call an excel function with powershell

Tags: microsoft-excel, powershell

I wonder how can I call a fucntion using powershell?

Normally in excel to find how many "string" is used in a row we use

```
=NB.SI(range,"string").
```

I would like to call this function `(=NB.SI(range,"string") )` with a powershell script.

Is it possible?

I tried to use`$objExcel.worksheetFunction.Match("string",range)` but it wasn't useful.

is there an other way ?

Comment: In what scenario would you need this sort of control?

Comment: $range=$Sheet2.Cells.Item($rowName+4,$colName+$k)
     $valeur=$objExcel.WorksheetFunction.Match($range,"Conforme")
     $sheet3.Cells.Item($rowAdresseIp+$k,$colAdresseIp+1)= $valeur                                 I’m trying to know how many times the word « Conforme » is used in a certain column,then save the result in an other sheet

Comment: Why use Powershell, could you not just do this in Excel on the other sheet?

Comment: No sir,because i'm trying to create a script,that can make this in an automatic way..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a resource that can help you with your query.

## Open New Excel Workbook / WorkSheet

```
$Excel = new-object -comobject excel.application
$ExcelWordBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Add()
$ExcelWorkSheet = $ExcelWordBook.Worksheets.Add()
$Excel.Visible = $true
```

https://sqlnotesfromtheunderground.wordpress.com/2014/01/25/modifying-excel-documents-with-powershell/

Comment: Hello sir!i found an easy solution to this problem :using the CountIF function

Comment: Glad it worked for you.

Comment: If this sorted out your question, mark it as an accepted answer so it can help others.